# Existe algum tipo de chat privado no SOpt?

Tags: suporte

Em alguns momentos, descubro ótimas pessoas aqui no site que eu gostaria de discutir, me informar mais sobre algo e falar sobre coisas que talvez nem tenham ligação com programação.

O problema é que não dá para fazer isso mandando uma pergunta no site ou enchendo os comentários de uma pergunta séria com besteiras. Então eu estava pensando se existe algum tipo de chat privado aqui no site (eu sei que existe o [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com), mas a minha pergunta é sobre um chat privado). Se não existe, já pensaram em criar um ?

Comment: Existe sim: [chat]

Comment: Tambem disponível no menu de navegação. "Stack Overflow em Portugues  - ajuda **chat** logout"

Comment: Além desse tem um no Telegram, mas esse é privado mesmo (não pertence à SE). No começo foi aberto pra quem queria, mas como acabou gerando problema agora só entra com convite. Como receber convite? Sendo um usuário dedicado que mostre que está querendo uma comunidade alinhada com a qualidade e tem interesse sobre o funcionamento do site. Não vou dizer que não possa pedir, até porque o chat não é meu e não posso gerar convites, mas acredito que quem é novo no site nem adianta pedir. De toda forma participe ativamente no chat oficial e quem sabe alguém possa convidar. Sem manter esperanças.

Comment: Pessoal, o chat que me refiro é o privado, igual a de redes sociais onde você conversa com somente uma pessoa. Eu dei uma olhada aqui no link que mostraram e pelo que eu estou vendo esse chat é público e mesmo que tenha a opção **Gallery**, ainda assim qualquer um pode entrar como diz aqui.

Comment: Eu penso o seguinte, para que chat privado em site técnico? Se aqui relacionamentos pessoais são considerados ruído então não tem motivo para conversas serem privadas ou ocultas.

Comment: Mesmo que existisse eu com certeza não vejo utilidade em MP (mensagem privada) no site, aqui a ideia é compartilhar ideias, se necessitar de privacidade então o motivo é outro, pode ser buscando alguém para realizar um trabalho ou participar de um projeto e nisto é melhor pedir um contato pessoal e dar seguimento por fora. Por falar nisso aqui no site e chat meio que indiretamente já consegui alguns trabalhos.

Comment: E se for privado sem que seja de comum acordo (primeiro aceitar a pessoa antes dela poder escrever qualquer mensagem), é fundamental que nunca exista. O que tem de imbecil (nesse caso eu posso usar essa expressão, pq estou me referindo a ocorrencias fora do site) querendo tirar satisfação de fechamento de postagem usando outras redes não é brincadeira, se tiver chat privativo aqui provavelmente vai não apenas aumentar o problema como também ser usado para uma série de coisas não construtivas, como já mencionado pelos colegas.

Comment: @Bacco, você também recebe e-mail sendo xingado por causa de pergunta fechada? Pensava que era só comigo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques email não, mas em outras redes tem sempre algum floco de neve indignado. Ja teve pessoa que perguntou educadamente, ai é mera inconveniência, mas tem gente que vem procurar criar caso mesmo. E é engraçado que esse segundo é quase sempre o mesmo perfil de analfabeto funcional misturado com paraquedista.